# Modifying breeze entity

Tags: knockout.js, breeze

```
 <div class="span4" data-bind="with: singleQaItem">
      <div class="span6">
        Qa Item Grouping <br /><input type="text" list="editQaItemGroupings" data-bind="value: QaItemGrouping().QaItemGroupingDesc" autocomplete="off">
       <datalist id="editQaItemGroupings">
        </datalist>
     </div>
 </div>
```

In the above html, singleQaItem is a breeze entity which also contains a foreign key property which is fetched using .expand. That property is QaItemGrouping().QaItemGroupingDesc to which the datalist control is bound.

In the UI when I modify the value of this property and save, I find that breeze is actually modifying the QaItemGrouping entity as it gets the entityState modified for this entity. But I am not modifying the QaItemGrouping entity. I am modifying the QaItemGrouping().QaItemGroupingDesc property which belongs to singleQaItem entity.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the *originalValues* property on the **QaItemGrouping** entity.  This will show you whatever properties you may have "inadvertently" changed.

```
var originalValues = theModifiedQaItemGroup.entityAspect.originalValue;
```

Comment: That's what is my question. Neither UI has any element bound to QaItemGrouping entity nor I am changing that entities value in the code. I am just binding QaItemGrouping().QaItemGroupingDesc in my code where QaItemGrouping is navigation property in singleQaItem entity. How come changing the navigation property is actually changing the original entity ?

Comment: Which "property" is changing? This is what the originalValues will tell you.

Comment: QaItemGroupingDesc property which I am binding to the datalist control

Comment: And is the originalValue the same as the current value?

Comment: No, its changing. Basically I am changing the navigation property of the entity, but breeze is also changing the value in the actual entity.

Comment: Not sure, if this is happening because I am not binding the control with the ID property (since its the navigation property). I cannot bind the control with ID property because its datalist control.

Comment: When I replace the datalist control with dropdown box and bind it to the ID property instead of QaItemGrouping().QaItemGroupingDesc, the problem gets solved.